# How to decode steam image url of thing?

Tags: api, decode, steam

Steam images have url like this:

```
http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXQ9QVcJY8gulRNRULFV_eS1M7DQEh4IEtDt7ekOQYu1aOQcGgSutizwIPYw6-mYe-AzzhQ68Mj2rmRpd-g3gXm80s9Zm_2cZjVLFH7KrlnRw/330x192
```

In the API can find these string:

```
-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXQ9QVcJY8gulRNRULFV_eS1M7DQEh4IEtDt7ekOQYu1aOQcGgSutizwIPYw6-mYe-AzzhQ68Mj2rmRpd-g3gXm80s9Zm_2cZjVLFH7KrlnRw
```

Is there a way to decrypt it?

Comment: Looks like Base64, but it doesn't decode to plaintext.

Comment: Not standard Base64, it has characters not in the standard Base64 character set such as "\_" and "-". But there are [variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) Base64 character sets that typically substitute "-" and "_" for "+"and "/" (in either order) with optional "=" padding.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that's off topic.

That's probably the image hash not the image itself. 
You should then make a call to download said image the same way a browser to.

From the steam API docs:

> img_icon_url, img_logo_url - these are the filenames of various images for the game. To construct the URL to the image, use this format: http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/{appid}/{hash}.jpg . For example, the TF2 logo is returned as "07385eb55b5ba974aebbe74d3c99626bda7920b8", which maps to the URL: [1]

Comment: the sticker thing has a link: [link](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/pinups_capsule/tamara.f08a506de4c348224193acf200003561288a565e.png) - this is the hash. But how can I get this link from  [link](http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXQ9QVcJY8gulRNRULFV_eS1M7DQEh4IEtDt7ekOQYu1aOQcGgSutizwIPYw6-mYe-AzzhQ68Mj2rmRpd-g3gXm80s9Zm_2cZjVLFH7KrlnRw/330x192)? These pics are have a different hash

Comment: Just build the link according to their standard URL + appid + hash.jpg